# Open an activity from web page

Tags: android, android-intent

My application has a payment feature witch is done over a browser. I want to redirect user back to the application after the payment is done.

I already added all these intent filters but no luck so far.

```
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            
            <data android:scheme="http" />
            <data android:scheme="https" />
            <data android:host="galshop.ir" />
            <data android:path="/" />
            <data android:path="/product-category" />
            <data android:path="/product-category/chicken" />
            
        </intent-filter>
```

Comment: Show what have you tried so far?

Comment: @chandmohd I already added the code.

Comment: Are you using webView to open web page ?

Comment: @chandmohd No, the device's browser.

Comment: Use WebView for opening web view pages . It would be easy to manage for app like call back n other stuff read about web view https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView

Answer (score 0):

I did not knew that it should also be implemented from the web as well.

intent://{VALUE}#Intent;scheme={SCHEMA};package={APPLICATION ID};end

ex: intent://123#Intent;scheme=galshop.ir;package=com.galshop.app;end

this will go to the `a` tag...